# How to have a.out file read text file through terminal by typing "a.out < textfilename.txt"

Tags: c++, command-line-arguments

I'm new to programming and I couldn't find an answer to my problem.

This is the code I have to have my program open and read the text file I want while running it on the terminal:

```
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, string *argv[])
{

    string fileName;
    getline(cin, fileName);
    ifstream infile(fileName.c_str());


    int total[26] = {0};


    if (!infile)
    {
        cout << "Error opening file" << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    char b;
    while (infile.get(b))         
    {
        if (isalpha(b))     
        {
            b = toupper(b);   



            int index = b - 'A';  

            total[index]++;      
        }
    }
```

I can run the program and type the file I want to open through the terminal but my instructor's program can open the file by typing the following in the terminal:

> a.out < text.txt

When I use getline instead of using fstream, it reads the file but not the entire file (until it reaches EOF). I'm not sure how I'm suppose to code this. (The assignment was submitted, this is just for my own reference)

Comment: "[a.out](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A.out)" is the default output file name for some compilers (e.g. GCC) - not to be confused with the file format of the same name (now deprecated).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When somebody does a redirect using the `<` character, that file **becomes** the standard input. So `cin` will contain the contents of `text.txt`. Since cin is a `istream` you can just do:

```
while (cin.get(b)) {
   // what you've got now...
}
```